# Transposing data frames in R via unstack

Tags: r, data-transformation

I want to transpose a data frame in R with `unstack`. Consider the two data frames, `a` and `b`:

```
> a
   count state
1 199665  RSTO
2   4147  RSTR
3  31274    S1
4      1    S2
5   2522    S3
6 118009    SF
> b
   count state
1  31956  RSTO
2  11689  RSTR
3   6702    S1
4   2838    S2
5   6268    S3
6 672561    SF
```

My problem is that unstacking a single one does not work:

```
> formula(a)
count ~ state
> unstack(a)
        res
RSTO 199665
RSTR   4147
S1    31274
S2        1
S3     2522
SF   118009
```

However, if I concatenate `a` and `b`, `unstack` works as expected.

```
> unstack(rbind(a,b))
    RSTO  RSTR    S1   S2   S3     SF
1 199665  4147 31274    1 2522 118009
2  31956 11689  6702 2838 6268 672561
```

Why is this happening? Does the groups (i.e., the RHS of the formula) need to repeat for `unstack` to work properly? How can I make `unstack` work with a single data frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `rbind(a, b)` creates a single data frame, so that's not it. The unexpected behavior of `unstack(a)` results from the fact that you only have one observation (`count`) per factor level (`state`). To see what's going on, you have to look at the `unstack()` function.

```
# list source code for unstack()'s method for a data frame
> getS3method("unstack", "data.frame")
function (x, form, ...) 
{
    form <- if (missing(form)) 
        stats::formula(x)
    else stats::as.formula(form)
    if (length(form) < 3) 
        stop("'form' must be a two-sided formula")
    res <- c(tapply(eval(form[[2L]], x), eval(form[[3L]], x), 
        as.vector))
    if (length(res) < 2L || any(diff(unlist(lapply(res, length))) != 
        0L)) 
        return(res)
    data.frame(res)
}
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

The relevant bits are `c(tapply(eval(form[[2L]], x), eval(form[[3L]], x), as.vector))` and `data.frame(res)`. The first expression here is equivalent to

```
> c(tapply(a$count, a$state, as.vector))
  RSTO   RSTR     S1     S2     S3     SF 
199665   4147  31274      1   2522 118009
```

The output of `tapply()` is a 1-dimensional array if the provided function only returns one value when applied to the data in each level of the factor. `c()` strips the class, thus returning a numeric vector. `data.frame(<vector>)` creates a data frame with one variable equal to that vector. Compare this to what happens with two observations per condition:

```
> ab <- rbind(a, b)
> c(tapply(ab$count, ab$state, as.vector))
$RSTO
[1] 199665  31956

$RSTR
[1]  4147 11689

$S1
[1] 31274  6702

$S2
[1]    1 2838

$S3
[1] 2522 6268

$SF
[1] 118009 672561
```

Here, the function provided for `tapply()` returns a vector with two elements for each level of the factor. The result then is a list with as many components as you have factor levels, each component containing the result of the supplied function for that level. All components have equal length, hence `data.frame(<list>)` returns a data frame where each component becomes a variable (data frames are special lists with components of equal length).

Now, another question would be if the behavior of `unstack()` is sensible in a case like yours. If this is of practical importance, you can add an id-variable and use `reshape()` instead.

```
> a$id <- 1
> reshape(a, direction="wide", v.names="count", timevar="state", idvar="id")
  id count.RSTO count.RSTR count.S1 count.S2 count.S3 count.SF
1  1     199665       4147    31274        1     2522   118009

> ab$id <- rep(1:2, each=nrow(a))
> reshape(ab, direction="wide", v.names="count", timevar="state", idvar="id")
   id count.RSTO count.RSTR count.S1 count.S2 count.S3 count.SF
1   1     199665       4147    31274        1     2522   118009
11  2      31956      11689     6702     2838     6268   672561
```

Comment: Thanks for the illumination, that's quite a detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

To get unstacking of `a` similar to `rbind(a,b)` you can simply transpose the result:

```
> t(unstack(a))
      RSTO RSTR    S1 S2   S3     SF
res 199665 4147 31274  1 2522 118009
```

You will get a `matrix` instead of `data.frame` though.

It is also possible to use the `cast` function from package **reshape**:

```
> cast(~state,data=a,value="count")
  value   RSTO RSTR    S1 S2   S3     SF
1 (all) 199665 4147 31274  1 2522 118009
```

For the `rbind(a,b)` with added `id` column the cast will give you the following:

```
> ab <- rbind(a,b)
> ab$id=rep(1:2,each=nrow(a))
> cast(id~state,data=ab,value="count")
  id   RSTO  RSTR    S1   S2   S3     SF
1  1 199665  4147 31274    1 2522 118009
2  2  31956 11689  6702 2838 6268 672561
```

Comment: The `cast` functions is really neat.

Comment: @Matthias, yes it is. I say a prayer to Hadley Wickham everytime I use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Caracal has answered the question. Here are some additional pieces of information.

Try this:

```
require(stats)
formula(PlantGrowth)
x = PlantGrowth[c(1,11,21),]
y = PlantGrowth[c(1,2,11,12,21,22),]
x
unstack(x)
y
unstack(y)
```

The output:

```
>     x
   weight group
1    4.17  ctrl
11   4.81  trt1
21   6.31  trt2
>     unstack(x)
      res
ctrl 4.17
trt1 4.81
trt2 6.31
>     y
   weight group
1    4.17  ctrl
2    5.58  ctrl
11   4.81  trt1
12   4.17  trt1
21   6.31  trt2
22   5.12  trt2
>     unstack(y)
  ctrl trt1 trt2
1 4.17 4.81 6.31
2 5.58 4.17 5.12
```

We just have to define a new unstack function:

```
NewUnstack <- function(x)
{
 df = unstack(x)
 if(dim(df)[2]==1)
 {
  df = t(df)
 }
 return(df)
}
```

Here we go:

```
> NewUnstack(x)
    ctrl trt1 trt2
res 4.17 4.81 6.31
> NewUnstack(y)
  ctrl trt1 trt2
1 4.17 4.81 6.31
2 5.58 4.17 5.12
```